On China's labor law and industrial overcapacity
Regarding the issue of overcapacity in China, I know its root causes, and a significant factor is the connection between overcapacity and China's labor laws. When China joined the WTO, it committed to implementing a five-day, eight-hour workweek. However, in practice, many companies and factories in China have serious issues with excessive overtime. In 2019, Chinese programmers launched a project on GitHub called "996.ICU" (see at https://github.com/996icu/996.ICU) to resist labor exploitation. For more on the "996 working hour system," see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/996_working_hour_system. China has a large population, and if employees work long hours, the production capacity can be enormous.
My Question:
I would like to know if there are ways for developed countries to pressure China to enforce labor laws.

The title question is about "labor law and industrial overcapacity" but in the text you then go on a long essay about "exploitation" and suicidal mass killings (the latest one being officially due to the killer's divorce and subsequent financial squabbles). At long last you ask about "ways for developed countries to pressure China to enforce labor laws". There are far too many different issues here. You should confine your question to just one.

@user182601 Thank you for pointing out the issue with my question. I have revised it.

Yeah, way too pushy and long. There are ways to ask whether other countries can pressure China to adhere to labor standards in international treaties or whatever, but the treatise on how bad their labor practices are needs to be made much shorter and neutral. The first paragraph would be more than sufficient by itself to establish that some labor problems exist in China and motivate the question.

@Obie2.0 I sincerely apologize for my poor language skills. I just wanted to add more facts to illustrate how severe the labor issues in China truly are.

Although interesting in its own right, I'm not sure what the point is of the long prologue to the question, and many parts of it are disputable.
You say long working hours "exacerbates overcapacity in China due to the sheer number of workers". In fact, China has a policy of overcapacity, because it wants abundance rather than scarcity, it wants flexibility and resilience in its economy, and it wants the maximum share of world exports in order to drive its industrial development and the industrial experience of its workforce, which it treats like a form of national capital accumulation.
The main way of pressuring China into labour standards would be to tariff its exports and deprive it of orders for production, but that is not the agenda of why Western liberals trade with China. They trade to attack Western workers and drive down labour standards.
China realised this pattern of the low-wage offshoring of Western liberals decades ago, and by the 1980s they'd adopted the explicit position of ensuring that they would benefit from the next round of attacks on Western workers by Western liberals. And so they did.
Unlike Western liberals, China is genuinely trying to develop its own people and national economic capability, and whilst it will tolerate oppressive working conditions in order to acquire work in the first place, it will not easily tolerate Western liberals then removing that work again so as to float to the next lower-wage economy. That one-way gate, supervised by the Chinese state, is the crucial difference from other corrupt states that are simply in cahoots with Western liberals to attack workers and grow profits.
Moreover, China must be prepared for an impending war against Western liberals who will try to destroy the Chinese regime for this reason and will exploit any weakness to do so. That's the real reason for the "over-capacity", because it is setting the target level of capacity to suit various contingencies, both the evolution of its own economy and the needs of military confrontation.

Thank you for your answer! I also upvoted your answer. I noticed that the number of upvotes on your answer went from 2 to -1 all of a sudden, which I find strange. Honestly, I’ve said so much just to convey one point: the fact is that China has not implemented the 5-day, 8-hour workweek as stipulated in its labor laws. The question is, how can China be made to enforce this labor law? For instance, can the EU or the US demand that China implement the 5-day, 8-hour workweek as prescribed by its labor laws?

The 2024 Nobel laureate in Economics, who wrote Why Nations Fail, mentions that unless external forces with greater power intervene, it is difficult to achieve significant change through domestic forces alone.

@Tom, military competition between nations I guess is a background feature of the 20th century. The Bolshevik revolution succeeded because the West was tired from WW1 and couldn't muster soldiers willing to attack Russia. Mao's revolution succeeded similarly after WW2 when the West was already tired out and couldn't mobilise soldiers to fight the scale of it (as illustrated by the American fate in Vietnam).

For what it's worth, I didn't downvote because of anything to do with "liberals", but because, despite criticising the length and irrelevancy of most of OP's post, you did the same thing yourself. The only part of this post which could be said to be answering the question is "the main way of pressuring China into labour standards would be to tariff its exports and deprive it of orders for production". The rest is just a biased opinion piece, bordering on conspiracy theorising, with little relevancy to the question. The answer can be improved by focussing more on the question.

@JBentley, some of the supplementary information was to explain both why the Chinese regime has an interest for now in keeping standards low, and also why Western liberals have an interest in keeping standards permanently low. The OP seemed to proceed from uncertainty whether China could be coerced into higher standards, rather than that the West actually wants to enforce low standards abroad. The final paragraph was remarking on whether "over-capacity" - the thing which the OP says is the result of low standards - is even real or not.

Yeesss, if China exploits its workers (and look a coal mining deaths stats as a metric), it is, of course, the fault of Western l̶i̶b̶e̶r̶a̶l̶s̶ bourgeois.

@ItalianPhilosopher, it is to the extent that China are playing the liberals at their own game, and beating them at it. China employs more coal miners than the entire rest of the world combined - we in the UK have fewer coal mining deaths not because it's safer here, but because the liberals offshored our entire coal mining industry and left fellas on the scrapheap and their sons following them to die of drug overdoses instead. I would talk of the bourgeoisie, but liberals are a much wider force of lick-boot defenders of the bourgeoisie.
